# Go: Распарсить json в обьект

Tags: json, парсер, golang

Помогите пожалуйста кодом, стоит задача распарсить json в обьект, трудность возникла с описанием структуры для фрагмента json. 
Представьте что есть json вида:

```
OriginalDetailsGroups: [
          {LocationId: 19482, GroupId: -654, MakeId: 654, MakeName: "Cardone Select", DetailNum: "262940",…},
          { SelectedOriginalDetailsGroupId: -654 }
]
```

Объект массива я описал как:

```
Type ODGItem {
AnalogDetails // null
BestAnalogPrice float
BestDaysDetail // null
BestExpectedDeliveryDays int
BestOriginalPrice float
BestPriceAnalog //null
BestPriceDetail //null
DetailNameRus string
DetailNum string
DetailParts //null
DetailsOnMap //null
GroupId int
IsOriginal bool
LocationId int
MakeId int
MakeName string
PartOfDetails //null
SearchFilteringStat *SearchFilteringStat_
SubstDetails //null
VisibleNum string 
}
```

Нужно описать объект в который входит объект OriginalDetailsGroup, и тут у меня возникает вопрос: как объявить в нём объект OriginalDetailsGroup?

```
type SearchResult struct {
   FuzzySearchDetails //null
   LimitationsCheckResult *LimitationsCheckResult
   OriginalDetailsGroups ???
   SelectedOriginalDetailsGroupId //null
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно, приведите пожалуйста json в виде текста, а не картинки

Answer (score 0):

Чем вас не устраивает срез?

```golang
OriginalDetailsGroups []ODGItem
```

Comment: Приведите пример JSON-ответа _текстом_ в вопросе. Иначе я совершенно не понимаю, что вам  нужно.

Comment: Так. Я ошибся, будучи в состоянии "очень хочется спать но нужно работать", мне приведилось, буд-то в OriginalDetailsGroups вслед за массивами идёт строка "SelectedOriginalDetailsGroupId: -654", но как я вижу сейчас, эта строка идёт вслед за объектом OriginalDetailsGroups. Похоже мой вопрос изначально лишён смысла. Но всё таки мне интересно, как можно было бы распарсить данный объект если бы вслед за массивами в объекте OriginalDetailsGroups содержался бы обьект со строкой?

Comment: Переписал вопрос в соответствии с тем что меня интересует.

Comment: @анонимныйвопрошатель То, что вы написали, не является корректным JSON.

Comment: Но если он таковой есть и его требуется обработать, как такое можно сделать средствами go?

Comment: Можно, конечно! Просто напишите свой парсер для своего «диалекта» JSON. Иначе это довольно странный вопрос. Данные либо являются корректным JSON, либо нет.